# How to make React CSS import component-scoped?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have several components which have the following CSS/component structure

`About/style.css`

```
.AboutContainer {
    # Some style
}

p > code {
    # Some style
}
```

And I import the CSS in the componet as follows

`About/index.js`

```
import './style.css';

export default class About extends Component {
    render() {
         # Return some component
    }
}
```

However, the CSS is imported in the `<header>` section and stays global-scope.

I was expecting CSS to be:

1. Component-scoped in a way that the style is only applied to things that are **only** rendered within this component.
2. Style for this component would disappear if the component is unmounted.

However, when inspecting from the browser, the styles are specified at the `<header>` section and gets applied to all the components

```
<header>
   // Stuff
   <style type="text/css">style for component About</style>
   <style type="text/css">style for component B</style>
   <style type="text/css">style for component C</style>
   // Stuff
</header>
```

How do I import CSS to be component-scoped? It seems like I'm understanding CSS import in React ES6 incorrectly.

I was following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d)

---

**Edit**

Answer by Brett is correct. However, my problem turns out to be somewhere else. I created my app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which basically simplifies setups required to do React. It include WebPack, Babel and other things to get started. The default WebPack config that it uses did not set [module option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/README.md#modules) for the `css-loader` so it defaulted to `false`, and as a result the local-scoping was not enabled.

Just for additional info, it seems like create-react-app does not have straightforward way to customize WebPack config, but there seem to be numerous how-to workarounds on the web.

Comment: Take a look at CSS modules - https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: Something is broken at Stackoverflow, when a well-formulated question gets answered by "this shiny library solves your problems", without addressing the problem. The question is updated with the right answer (thanks for that @Harry Cho!) but gets zero upvotes.

Comment: You can use css modules with create-react-app without ejecting according to this blog : https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-css-modules/

Comment: rename mystyle.css to mystyle.module.css and import it to use css modules in a react app created using `create-react-app`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It sounds like [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), or many of the other CSS-in-JS packages, does what you want. Others include [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/) (my current favorite), [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/), or many of the packages [here](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js).

> A CSS Module is a CSS file in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default. All URLs (url(...)) and @imports are in module request format (./xxx and ../xxx means relative, xxx and xxx/yyy means in modules folder, i. e. in node_modules).

Here's a quick example:

Let's say we have a React component like:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles/button.css';

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className={styles.button}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
export default Button;
```

and some CSS in `./styles/button.css` of:

```
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

After CSS Modules performs it's magic the generated CSS will be something like:

```
.button_3GjDE {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

where the `_3DjDE` is a randomly generated hash - giving the CSS class a unique name.

**An Alternative**

A simpler alternative would be to avoid using generic selectors (like `p`, `code`, etc) and adopt a class-based naming convention for components and elements. Even a convention like [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) would help in preventing the conflicts you're encountering.

Applying this to your example, you might go with:

```
.aboutContainer {
  # Some style
}

.aboutContainer__code {
  # Some style
}
```

Essentially all elements you need to style would receive a unique classname.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe [react-scoped-css](https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css) will help. Btw, I'm the author of this lib, if you find anything broken or simply want to improve it, you can always raise an issue or send a pr.

Comment: After hours of debugging, I realized that this package is not compatible with framer-motion components, e.g. motion.button, motion.input etc.

Answer (score 17):

Because you mentioned you used `create-react-app`, the solution here is quite easy change just `style.css` to `style.module.css`, it will look like this:

```
import styles from "./style.module.css"
<button className={styles.button}>blabla</button>
```

More info on this article:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-sass-and-css-modules-with-create-react-app-83fa8b805e5e

Answer (score 12):

You can use SASS (.scss) to imitate scoped CSS.

Say you need to use bootstrap in only one component (to avoid conflicts). Wrap the component in `<div className='use-bootstrap'>` and then created a .scss file like so:

```
.use-bootstrap {   
  // Paste bootstrap.min.css here
}
```

Comment: that does not resolve the whole issue - the CSS selectors will be concatenated (if sass nesting is used), but what about the markup? inner selectors are still in danger of being not unique

Comment: this would work, but the relevant paths used for `@font-face` would result in errors in console...

Comment: this worked fine for me. I included the hole Bulma framework using

.use-bulma {
  @import "bulma";
}

Answer (score 8):

Use this file naming convention `[name].module.css`
and see documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

**JSX File**

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './MyPage.module.scss';

const MyPage = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.myDiv}>
            My Page
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyPage;
```

**Styles File**

```
    .myDiv {
        color: #f3f3f3;
        font-family: "Cambria";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simple solution (*without using: Css-modules or css-in-js*) is to add a suffix to your class selectors like this:

```
className="btn__suffix"
```

if your component is named: **FileUpload.tsx** so your **__suffix** would be **__fu**, i took the first character of each word (here: `File` and `Upload`).

the end result would be:

```
import './style.css';

export default class About extends Component {
render() {
      Return (
         <div className="container__fu">
           ...
         </div>
              )
   }
}
```

And in the Css part, your file would be:

```
.container__fu {
   ...
}
```