# How to add scoped css in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

Is there a React equivalent of `scoped css` as in Vue that's **super easy** to work with, without a bunch of re-writes? One which I can just import an existing css file, and hook it up to a component, and it just works?

**In Vue**, it's as easy as

```html
<style scoped src="./boxes.css"></style>
```

And Bam! Your css is now scoped to your component.

**Is there anything similar in React**? Something like

```
// import the css file
import styles from "./boxes.css";

// hook it to a component, or using any other methods
@inject(styles)
class Boxes extends Component {
  render(){
    <div className='container'>
       /* must support multiple classes out-of-the-box, unlike CSSModule where you have to 
       re-write into a super long array like className={[styles.box, styles.green, styles.large]} */
      <div className='box green large'></div> 
      <div className='box red small'></div> 
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: you need that: https://www.styled-components.com/ ... it's so superior to VUE scoped css

Comment: example of how vue is simple and powerful out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried Svelte? ... It has it built in ... and is much more performant than React :)

Answer (score 17):

Every answer here is about CSS Modules, but scoped styles in Vue works another way.

Here the library for React that works like `<style scoped>` in Vue: https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css

Input:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Title.scoped.css'

const Title = props => {
  return (
    <h1 className="title">
      <p>{props.children}</p>
    </h1>
  )
}

export default Title
```

Output:

```html
<h1 class="title" data-v-hi7yyhx>
```

```css
.title[data-v-hi7yyhx] {}
```

Answer (score 9):

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

**Button.module.css**

```
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**another-stylesheet.css**

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

**Button.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

**Result**: No clashes from other .error class names

```
<!-- This button has red background but not red text -->
<button class="Button_error_ax7yz">Error Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like that in React. 3 common ways to style:

1. Import a css file then use `className` like normal HTML => nothing have to learn, just add an `import` and you ready to go.
2. Css-in-js libraries. I prefer `styled-component` - it's awesome.
3. Inline style

Comment: but 1. won't be scoped, it'll affect all other components

Comment: I found your question deplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped). More infor about scope CSS in React [link](https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e)

Comment: For styled-components  see: [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this...

Coming from Vue, I faced this issue as well.
I was able to device a flexible scoped styling structure for each component

Consider the below.

```
const useOwnStyles = () => ({
    hero: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
        height: "300px",
    },
    // add more classes
});

const Home = () => {
    const classes = useOwnStyles();
    return (
        <div style={classes.hero}>
           <div>My Section</div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do it exactly the way Vue does it, but [there are plenty of libraries](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js) for doing this kind of thing, which gives you lots of choice for however you prefer to work. My personal recommendation is [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).

Comment: Why isn't it possible in React?

Comment: It's _probably_ possible with React, but no one's really had a real need for it. The current solutions for styling have been satisfactory for the most part

Comment: I think people will be looking for this feature if they have Vue experience. I did Vue and React. And if scoped styling feature of Vue is available in react it will remove verbose JS className code in components.  From `className={\`text-3xl mt-4 ${styles.yo}\`}` to  `className="text-3xl mt-4 yo"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css modules with the webpack [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

It will scope your css by adding a unique hash in the name of your css classes.

For exemple if you have a ComponentA with a style definition in a file named stylesA.css and a ComponentB with a style definition in a file named stylesB.css like:

```js
import * as React from 'react'

const stylesA = require('./stylesA.css')
const stylesB = require('./stylesB.css')

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  render <div className={stylesA.container}>
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
  render <div className={stylesB.container}>
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  render <div>
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
  </div>
}
```

your HTML file will result as

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="container-[HASH FOR A]">
      </div>
      <div class="container-[DIFFERENT HASH FOR B]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```