# How to select an element inside a React container using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code here:

```
<Grid container className={"home-page-container"}>
            <Grid item xs={1}/>
            <Grid item xs={10} >                
                <h1>Play "Monsters on the way" to earn Crypto and NFTs</h1>
                <h2>This is a project for my thesis</h2>
                <p>Nothing to say, just press PLAY and slay monsters</p>
                {/* <Unity unityContext={unityContext}
                    className={"unityCanvas hide-in-small-screen"}
                />; */}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}/>
        </Grid>
```

And I have this CSS file:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I select just the  inside the Grid container using that CSS?

Comment: Your container has a class on it. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: Or are you asking how to [scope CSS to a particular instance of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849070/how-to-add-scoped-css-in-react)?

Comment: @isherwood I've tried to add .home-page-container.h1 selector but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: That's because you're not doing a child selector correctly. Your selector looks for an element with both classes, not one inside the other. I suggest a stroll through the fundamentals of CSS.

Comment: You're right, I'll definitely read the fundamentals of selectors again! Thanks :D

Comment: Also, `h1` isn't a class, so it won't have a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use => .grid
but it will select all grids in your component.

However, you can give className to your grid .. then you can style it with the new class