# React js css stylesheet applied to more than one component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a **Parent.js** component with a child component **Child.js** inside of it.

- **Parent.js** imports **parents.css**
- **Child.js** imports **child.css**

If I define this in **child.css**:

```
.example {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

How come I'm able to use this className in the **Parent.js** component as well despite not specifying it in the **parent.css**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make React CSS import component-scoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped)

Comment: You can use CSS-in-JS or CSS modules for the specifying styles separately.
This might help: https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use unique class names, CSS Modules or some other alternatives available for scoping CSS styles to any component in React, styles specified in any CSS file will be applied globally.

If you want to limit styles to any component, use CSS Modules or make sure every class name is unique in your project.

For details on how to use CSS Modules, see [Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet). You can also look at [9 Ways To Implement CSS in React JS](https://medium.com/@dmitrynozhenko/9-ways-to-implement-css-in-react-js-ccea4d543aa3) for other available alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using unique class names. For example, lets say you have multiple ListView components: MemberUsersListView, AdminUsersListView, TestUsersListView; and each of them needs to be styled differently. I would create the following CSS classes:

```
.MUListView{
  ...
}
.AUListView{
  ...
}
.TUListView{
  ...
}
```

I know this seem's annoying, but it's cleaner than applying inline styles and easier to implement on smaller projects.