# Changing the CSS for a React component has effect on all other pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I have a React component with the following files:

- src/components/HomePage/index.js
- src/components/HomePage/style.scss

The component is very simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div className="homepage">
            <h1>Landing page</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Within `style.scss` I am applying a style to all `<h1>` tags:

```
h1 {
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-family: "Cambria";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

And it works as expected. However, I now see that the h1 style within `styles.scss` is being applied to every h1 on my site, even on pages that do not use this component.

I am using Gatsby, but it's a React app at heart. My understanding is that React's code-splitting feature would take care of this, that the code from `style.scss` would only be included in bundles for any page that uses my component.

**It's the *why* that I am asking about**. I have two easy fixes:

- Wrap everything in `style.scss` in a `.homepage` wrapper
- Use CSS modules and rename the file to `style.module.scss`. When I see people do that they always do `import style from './style.module.scss' - is there a way to have CSS modules without assigning it to an object like that?

---

**Update**: Coming back to this question after spending a lot of time with React and I think there's a gap in the market for React styling. CSS modules is syntactically poor in my opinion and having to manually wrap everything in a `.home` tag to localise it is manual work I don't want to do. Someone should really create a React plugin that automatically does this so that whenever I have a file called `Home.js` and I import `Home.css` that all the CSS is automatically restricted to `Home.js` without me having to do anything special.

Comment: check this thread out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make React CSS import component-scoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped)

Comment: I understand that CSS modules will simply do the job of wrapping my CSS in a parent tag for me. My question is really about why code splitting does not take care of this? I thought the whole point of code splitting is that JS/CSS wasn't loaded until it was needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to localize CSS rules, then you would have to switch to [modular stylesheets](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) (works the same for sass stylesheets).

In your current structure, the component imports non-modular stylesheet and doesn't localize the changes with a unique identifier. Therfore added rules live in a global scope without a unique identifier that would localize them so that only selected components could understand them. That means that they are capable of easily overwriting the same-named rules which were previously established (import order matters here, because it would dictate how the bundler appends the output stylesheet).

So instead of holding component-related rules within `./style.scss` file, rename it to `./index.module.scss` and then you would utilize it within the component like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './index.module.scss';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.homepage}>
            <h1 className={style.heading}>Landing page</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

and your stylesheet would look like:

```
.heading {
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-family: "Cambria";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

**disclaimer**:

I've changed the styling convention from selecting elements by their tag, to selecting them by class, because targetting elements by tag is widely considered a bad practice [[ref]](https://frontstuff.io/you-need-to-stop-targeting-tags-in-css) , but if you want to maintain it, then you would have to provide a parent scope for such a rule (it already exists since the parent `<div/>` element has an assigned class.
In this case the implementation would look like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './index.module.scss';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.homepage}>
            <h1>Landing page</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

and styles:

```
.homepage {
    h1 {
        color: #f3f3f3;
        font-family: "Cambria";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution is what I have done. I am actually modifying the body tag in this CSS file too so I didn't want to go down the CSS modules route. I guess this just changes my understanding of code-splitting. So am I right in thinking that all CSS for all React components gets compiled into one big CSS bundle loaded on first load? If that's true then I really have no idea how code-splitting works.

Comment: That's pretty much correct (there might be deviations however, so don't cite me on this and treat it as a rule of thumb). Modules just prepend the rules with unique identifiers. But as stated within the answer, I think that the root of your problem is providing styles by tag type selectors - best to avoid it.

Comment: Just reading here and it looks like React does NOT implement code splitting by default - even flavours like Next.js and Gatsby - and that if you want to achieve what I thought was default behaviour you have to implement lazy loading through React.lazy(). Good to know! I will update my question to include this info. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can either go with the easiest way that is mentioned below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
    <div className = "home">
            <div className="homepage">
                <h1>Landing page</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

You can wrap whole html inside one div of particular component name

CSS:

```
.home h1 {
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-family: "Cambria";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

This is the easiest way. However this is my personal solution because I also face the same issues when I was beginner at react.

Comment: This solution is work great but if we use !important flag element style will override