# How can I get rid of '.module' part in ReactJS' CSS module names?

Tags: reactjs

How can use imports in ReactJS like this:

```
import styles from './Login.scss';
```

Instead of this:

```
import styles from './Login.module.scss';
```

The problem is, when I'm importing with the first syntax, no styles are imported.

(Edit: I used Create React App if that matters)

(Edit 2: Seems like I have to follow [this](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc) and use the solution from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1350#issuecomment-324481760).)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit importing stylesheets as a module by importing them as:

```js
import './Login.scss';
```

Then you could apply CSS classes like:

```js
<>
 <SomeComponent className="foobar"/>
<>
```

However be warned, that by importing them like this, the style rules contained in those files will live in a global scope.
If you would like to get more details, I think that this thread could help:

[Changing the CSS for a React component has effect on all other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093276/changing-the-css-for-a-react-component-has-effect-on-all-other-pages/63093419#63093419)