# How do I use a different css body without changing the style on the other components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have several folders, my folder structure looks like this:

- src

  - components

    - login

      - Login.js
      - Login.css
    - input

      - Input.js
      - Input.css

As you can see, I have several different component.
The `Input.css` looks like this:

```
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');


. body {
    background-color: green;
}
.account-settings .user-profile {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
.account-settings .user-profile .user-avatar img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.account-settings .user-profile h5.user-name {
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.account-settings .user-profile h6.user-email {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #9fa8b9;
}
.account-settings .about {
    margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.account-settings .about h5 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #007ae1;
}
.account-settings .about p {
    font-size: 0.825rem;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #cfd1d8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: .825rem;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #2e323c;
}

.card {
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

What I want is that I can use Input.css in Input.js without that has effects on the other components. If I use Input.css like this, the body changes and the bootstrap css has effects on other components. I do not want that.

What I tried:
Name
*Input.module.scss*

```
.xtest {
    @import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
    background-color: green;
}
h1 {
color: yellow;
}
. 
. 
. 
}
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import style from './Input.module.scss'




const Input = () => {

  const [profilPicture, setProfilPicture] = useState(false);


  
  return (
    <div className={style.xtest}>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div classNameName="container">
      <div className="row gutters">
        <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div className="card h-100">
            <div className="card-body">
              <div className="account-settings">
                <div className="user-profile">
                  <div className="user-avatar">
                    {profilPicture === false &&
                      <i className="far fa-user-circle"></i>
                    }
                    {profilPicture === true &&
                      <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png" alt="Maxwell Admin" />
                    }
                  </div>
                  <h5 className="user-name">Yuki Hayashi</h5>
                  <h6 className="user-email">yuki@Maxwell.com</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="about">
                  <h5>About</h5>
                  <p>I'm Yuki. Full Stack Designer I enjoy creating user-centric, delightful and human experiences.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div className="card h-100">
            <div className="card-body">
              <div className="row gutters">
                <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <h6 className="mb-2 text-primary">Personal Details</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="fullName" placeholder="Enter full name" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="eMail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="eMail" placeholder="Enter email ID" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="website">Website URL</label>
                    <input type="url" className="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Website url" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row gutters">
                <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <h6 className="mt-3 mb-2 text-primary">Address</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="Street">Street</label>
                    <input type="name" className="form-control" id="Street" placeholder="Enter Street" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="ciTy">City</label>
                    <input type="name" className="form-control" id="ciTy" placeholder="Enter City" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="sTate">State</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="sTate" placeholder="Enter State" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="zIp">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="zIp" placeholder="Zip Code" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row gutters">
                <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <div className="text-right">
                    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Input
```

However, when I use this scss, it also has no effects. Nothing happend at Input.js (background also turns not green). The `h1` tag is displayed in yellow, but not the body. And the bootstrap has an impact on all other components

But how can I use the Input.css without it having effects on the other css files?

- [How to make React CSS import component-scoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped)
- [Changing the CSS for a React component has effect on all other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093276/changing-the-css-for-a-react-component-has-effect-on-all-other-pages)

Answer (score 0):

`body` is an HTML element that must always exist, and must only exist once. Changing its styles will always change the styles globally. You cannot scope `body`, (as long as you're not working in the shadow DOM).

A better solution for your problem is, to wrap your component inside a `div` element. You can then style this one `div` element, without effecting the styles of any other components (if you scope it correctly).

Comment: Thanks. I understand about the body. What would be a solution with the bootstrap?

Comment: And with own defined tags in the scss the whole thing doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if you're using bootstrap or not, with both methods you can wrap components inside divs, just set the `background-color` directly for the class `xtest`. And it doesn't work with own defined tags because CSS Modules only work with classes.