# import a CSS file to only one compoenent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scope, components

I'm rendering HTML received from an API call like this :

```
{props.content &&
                    <div className="container-HTMLContent">
                        {textToDisplay && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textToDisplay }} className="my-4"></div>}

                        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} className="underline">{isOpen ? "Voir moins" : "Lire la suite +"}</button>
                    </div>
                }
```

I'd like to style this HTML so I created a style.css file, and I imported it ONLY in this component but the CSS applies to all the website.

Example of css :

```
h1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  font-weight: 800 !important;
  font-size: 1.7rem !important;
  line-height: 1.2 !important;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
  line-height: 1.2 !important;
}
```

How can I apply it to only this component that renders the html ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make React CSS import component-scoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using [scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).

Example of your SCSS:

```
.exclusive {
  h1 {
    border: 3px solid red;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
    font-size: 1.7rem !important;
    line-height: 1.2 !important;
  }

  h2 {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    font-size: 1.6rem !important;
    line-height: 1.2 !important;
  }
}
```

Wrap your component inside a div with the corresponding classname:

```
<div class="exclusive">
  <h1>John</h1>
  <h2>Doe</h2>
<div>
```