# import css in separate page in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React.

**Usually, I am importing the whole css files in index.html within public folder.**

But there is a css file that i cannot import globally (this is because web-publisher team worked on different pages and some of their css gets overriden)

Of course the best way to solve this would be to ask web-publisher team to unify their css work.

But i wanted to test if i could resolve this issue on my side (front-end)

**How to import css for specific React component?**

i tried this

```js
import "../../../public/css/mypage.css/"
```

=> error: falls outside src directory

also this:

```js
import "/public/css/mypage.css
```

=> also doesnt work

**My solution: should i move this css file into my src folder?**

**My folder Structure:**
public folder => css => mypage.css
public folder => index.html (where i usually import all css files)

src folder => App.js (i dont import css here)

Comment: whereever and however you import it wont change the fact that it will be overiden by stronger css selectors

Comment: And no matter i try to import css for specific component, the css works always globally within react framework right?

Comment: yes, react doesnt have any CSS encapsulation natively to my knowledge.

Comment: what is your folder structure? where is css and where is your react component?

Comment: ive edited my folder structure in the question. basically i have css files in public folder where i import into index.html which is in public folder.

Comment: Have you tried `import "/css/mypage.css"` yet?

Comment: i get an error: Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /css/mypage.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that i tried to import like you (`import "../../../public/css/mypage.css/"`), it worked. Maybe you want to check the path to see if it was correct.
[image]

Comment: no no the problem is even if you import specific css for a component within React, that css will apply for the entire React app because React is a single page application. Hence, my understanding is importing css for specific component is not possible in React.

Comment: Ohh, maybe you wanna check out css modules. And check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47090832/13329040)

Comment: O thanks so much so basically i need to use css module. Still, i think the web publisher should unify their work before giving their work to front-end.