# Nested div is centered horizontally and vertically in React but not in HTML

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Ideally the parent-div should be visible like following (I confirmed it by running index.html file attached at the end)

[image]

But when I am running my react application, I am seeing the parent-div as:

[image]

I am not sure why is this happening. I could not find much information on this. May be I need to learn more about certain concepts but not sure what! Can someone please help me with this.

```css
.centered-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: calc((0.5*30vh)*-1);   /* Half of the height */
  margin-left: calc((0.5*30vw)*-1);   /* Half of the width */
  border: 1pt solid rgb(192, 184, 184);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
}

.parent-div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1pt solid rgb(192, 184, 184);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="centered-div">
    <!-- Parent div without padding -->
    <div class="parent-div">
      <!-- Child div without top and left properties -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There must be other styles in your React app. Did you use your browser's document inspector to look at it? It should be fairly apparent what adds the extra space or alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I have same div name (centered-div) in my `Home.tsx` but it has different css file(which has additional flex properties defined). When I am clicking a button in `Home.tsx`, I am redirecting to the page I shared in the question using `window.location.href`. So, it looks like because of the flex properties in `Home.css`, my current page's `centered-div` is inheriting those flex and causing spaces. I thought that the css classes in separate files are scoped, are they not?

Comment: Not in React. CSS scoping is a [common request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090574/how-to-make-react-css-import-component-scoped).